# Same Postfix aliases for different domains

Tags: email, postfix, alias, mail-forwarding

I've got Postfix managing two different domains `one.com` and `two.com`, included in the `my destination` variable of the `main.cf` file.

I need an `/etc/aliases` file including something like this:

```
user@one.com: foo@three.com
user@two.com: bar@four.com
```

Since `/etc/aliases` syntax does not allow me to do this, how can I solve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `virtual_alias_maps` like so:

```
virtual_alias_maps  = hash:/etc/postfix/virtualalias
```

with content like this:

```
user@one.com foo@three.com
user@two.com bar@four.com
```

Of course, postfix needs to know how to handle the addresses. After that, don't forget to `postmap /etc/postfix/virtualalias` and to reload Postfix.

Read http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html